# Filtering javascript array by array of strings

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have an array of strings that looks like this

`arr = ['video-1', 'video-2', 'cpe-1', 'abc-1', 'abc-2']`

I can simply filter this out by doing:

`let newarr = arr.filter(item => item.indexOf('video') >= 0)`

`>> newarr = ["video-1", "video-2"]`

However, I tried to use an array of strings as an input to give multiple filter options by doing

```
let q = ['video', 'CPE']
let newarr2 = arr.filter(item => q.indexOf(item) >= 0)
```

But this gives me an empty array. What is the correct usage?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check whether `.some` of the keywords you want to include are included in the item.

Because the casing is different as well, call `toLowerCase()` on everything beforehand as well:

```js
const arr = ['video-1', 'video-2', 'cpe-1', 'abc-1', 'abc-2'];
const keywordsToFind = ['video', 'CPE'];
const keywordsToFindLower = keywordsToFind.map(s => s.toLowerCase());
const newarr2 = arr.filter(
  item => keywordsToFindLower.some(
    keywordToFind => item.toLowerCase().includes(keywordToFind)
  )
);
console.log(newarr2);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can make a regex from `q` to make this more efficient than using other array methods:

```js
const arr = ['video-1', 'video-2', 'cpe-1', 'abc-1', 'abc-2'];
const q = ['video', 'CPE'];

const re = RegExp(q.join("|"), "i");
const res = arr.filter(e => re.test(e));

console.log(res);
```

Comment: While valid for the requirements of the question, this solution assumes that none of the strings in `q` contain any RegEx characters. For example, in [this (hastily thrown together) case](https://tio.run/##RY7BCsMgEETv/QrxokIitNfQXkp@INfSgzXbYAhZoxJ68N@tNqG57A7zZocd1aq8dsaGesYeUtI4@0CUc@RKHmw1PWB9ZhXZ5aVIbWHz1EsfYkMRfqsMYM/mtPUtR1sh99gWtkMHmXYwtB/LFzmimTmNVFSEGiqaf8jnVP5Lvs0UwPF8dMuuDOADByH2OpxATjjwnBdNSl8), the `"c"` and the `"e"` are returned by the `filter`, when they shouldn't be.